# Splitting cells separated by a comma

Tags: excel, vba, split

okay guys i have seen a lot of questions about this but have not been able to find the answer i am looking for. I have been playing around with macro codes and trying to write some myself and big fail. So if anyone has a code that would do this, that would be awesome.

[image]

I need the Codes in column B seperated by a comma to be split into a new cell below and rest of the row copied with it. The range on this sheet is from Comumn A to N. Please see below for what i need.

[image]

The numbers in column B will always be 4 digits long and seperated by commas. I have found some codes i thought worked but all they did was copy the set of numbers and deleted the rest and repeatedly pasted the same number.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 2
Do Until Cells(x, 2) = ""
    splt = Split(Cells(x, 2), ",")
    If UBound(splt) > 0 Then
        Number = Cells(x, 1)
        Rows(x & ":" & x + UBound(splt) - 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        For Each e In splt
            Cells(x, 2) = Trim(e)
            Cells(x, 1) = Number
            x = x + 1
        Next e
    Else
        x = x + 1
    End If
Loop
```

If you will ever have codes that start with zero (i.e. 0432), make sure column B is formatted as text in your spreadsheet, or excel will convert it to 432 when it puts it into the cell.